# c# how to display sql value from wcf service in windows form app in datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, sql, wcf, datagridview

I'm new to wcf and I am trying to use wcf connect to sql and display values in a datagridview, how to do it?

In IProductsService.cs, I just did

```
[OperationContract]
Products[] getProducts();
```

and in Products.cs

```
[DataMember]
string productId, productName, location;

public Products(string productId1, string productName1, string location1)
{
    this.productId = productId1;
    this.productName = productName1;
    this.location = location1;                
}
```

ProductsService.svc.cs

```
namespace Products
{
    public Products[] getProducts()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection( "Data Source=111111;Initial Catalog=11111;User ID=111111;Password=11111");
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT productId, productName, location FROM Products", connection);

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        //Do something here to send value? how?
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Enumerate the reader and return the results?

Comment: Please check an answer or add more help to us

Answer (score 2):

```
public List<Prodict> getProducts()
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection( "Data Source=111111;Initial Catalog=11111;User ID=111111;Password=11111");
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT productId, productName, location FROM Products", connection);

    var productList = new List<Product>(); //Do Array, if it is better for you.

    using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            var product = new Product(rdr.GetValue(0).ToString(),rdr.GetValue(1).ToString(),rdr.GetValue(2).ToString());
            productList.Add(product);
        }
    }

    return productList;
}
```

Comment: `New` should be `new` , also since the method is returning an Array, a call to `ToArray` with return statement would work.

Comment: then what should I do to display products detail in the datagridview?